# Best way to test application services from outside the application

Tags: java, spring, nginx, keep-alive

I have a spring application that uses several services such as MySQL, PostgreSQL, and a Bing's location web service.  They all work fine and I have some unit and integration tests to make sure they are working correcly.

I was asked yesterday to create keepalive pages for each service that will tell if the service is available or not so my systems administrator can call these pages from nginx.

I know I can create a new controller with methods to verify each service but is that the best way to do this?  I think he will want to run these checks very often.  If anyone has any suggestions or links for more information I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go a different route for this, You can Create a spring service like this

```
@Component
public class MonitorService 
{
    public void checkServices()
    {
     //if(problem) send an e-mail notification, 
         //you can configure spring MailSender to do that
    }
}
```

Now you create a spring task scheduler to run this monitor at a fixed interval

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
  <task:scheduled ref="monitorService" method="checkServices" fixed-delay="1000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```